# Strings and UITableViewCells in iOS6

Tags: uitableview, nsstring, ios6

I am migrating an app from iOS5 to iOS6.  In one part of the app, the user selects a tab from a uitabbarviewcontroller at the bottom of the screen and it takes them to a uitableview.  When the user selects the tab, the code calls a web service and lists the most recent information that is attached to a piece of data that is stored with CoreData and kept on the device itself.

Anyway, when I am in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I construct a string out of the web service response, and set the text property on the detailTextLabel of the cell to the value of this string.

This never caused a problem in iOS5.  Now when I try to use this string in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, the compiler seems to think that my strings are really `NSIndexPath` variables.

So for example, if I try to check the length of the string, the app crashes, leaving me a message that says:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSIndexPath length]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x396cae64'
```

And similarly for any thing else that I would want to do with the string in that method.

A couple of other things:

1. It happens on both the simulator and on the device.
2. It has nothing to do with the string itself; that is, it's still working great on devices that still have iOS5 installed.  Also, I can set detailTextLabel.text to the value that I am using to set the string; I just can't explicitly use the string.

Has anybody else come across this?  If so, what was your solution?  I googled around and didn't see anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy that string,then use it.

First copy that string like

NSString *strTemp=[[NSString stringwithformat:@"%@",yourstring]copy];

now try to use strTemp where you want to use.